# Complete an animation even if mouse button is released

Tags: python, pygame

I just started making a game with Pygame two weeks ago.
I am making a game where the player can jump, move right and left. I also implemented an animation that plays when the character is idling.
However, I have great difficulty trying to make the character attack. This movement is rather complex, as I want to make the character move forward AND attack at the same time, so it's basically dashing forward. **It is triggered when the right mouse button is clicked.**
Until now, I've managed to load the character's attack animation; I've written some code now and it all seems all right EXCEPT that when I release the right mouse button, the animation stops.
I really want that **when the right mouse button is clicked, the character dashes forward and completes the animation. I don't want someone to hold their mouse button for the whole duration of the animation.** *For the code until now, the desired effect kind of happens, but I need to hold the button and after one cycle of the animation, it restarts*

So here's my code:

```
import pygame, time
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

background = pygame.image.load('images/background 1.jpeg')

#Long lists of all the frames I need for my animations
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('packs/!Charac1_right_run/tile000.png'), etc.]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('packs/!Charac1_left_run/tile000.png', etc.)]
idleForm = [pygame.image.load('packs/!Charac1_idle/tile000.png', etc.)]
atk_with_mvmt = [pygame.image.load('packs/!Charac1_atk_with_mvmt/tile000.png', etc.)]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.left = False
        self.right = False

        self.vel = 5

        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10

        self.isAtk_with_mvmt = False
        self.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0

        self.idleCount = 0
        self.walkCount = 0


    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 30:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.idleCount + 1 >= 30:
            self.idleCount = 0

        if self.atk_with_mvmtCount + 1 >= 30:
            self.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

        elif self.isAtk_with_mvmt:
            win.blit(atk_with_mvmt[self.atk_with_mvmtCount // 6], (self.x, self.y))
            self.atk_with_mvmtCount += 1

        else:
            win.blit(idleForm[self.idleCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.idleCount += 1


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global idleCount
    global atk_with_mvmtCount

    win.blit(background, (0, 0))  # This will draw our background image at (0,0)
    man1.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

#mainloop
man1 = player(50, 410, 64, 64)
run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:

            man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = True
            man1.x += (man1.vel) * 25
            man1.right = False
            man1.left = False




    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        man1.x -= man1.vel

        man1.left = True
        man1.right = False

        #man1.idle = False
        #man1.idleCount = 0

        man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = False
        #man1.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        man1.x += man1.vel

        man1.left = False
        man1.right = True

        #man1.idle = False
        #man1.idleCount = 0

        man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = False
        #man1.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0




    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2] is False:
        man1.right = False
        man1.left = False
        man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = False

        man1.walkCount = 0




    if not man1.isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man1.isJump = True
            man1.right = False
            man1.left = False
            man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = False

    else:
        if man1.jumpCount >= -10:
            man1.y -= (man1.jumpCount * abs(man1.jumpCount * 0.7)) * 0.35
            man1.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man1.jumpCount = 10
            man1.isJump = False


    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

So to sort things out a bit,

```
self.isAtk_with_mvmt = False
self.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0
```

Here I define the necessary variables. (upper block)

```
if self.atk_with_mvmtCount + 1 >= 30:
    self.atk_with_mvmtCount = 0
```

Here I reset the `self.atk_with_mvmtCount` value to allow multiple animations. (upper block)

```
    elif self.isAtk_with_mvmt:
        win.blit(atk_with_mvmt[self.atk_with_mvmtCount // 6], (self.x, self.y))
        self.atk_with_mvmtCount += 1
```

And here I basically say at what speed I cycle through the images. (upper block)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:

        man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = True
        man1.x += (man1.vel) * 25
        man1.right = False
        man1.left = False
```

That block is where I say what does the right mouse button do. (upper block)

As I said, I am trying to figure out how, with a single mouse click, the animation could play itself entirely without ending midway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the code inside the if-statement, create a boolean and set it to `True` in the if-statement and create another if-statement to run the code for the animation if the aforementioned boolean is true like so:

```
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]: 
            run_animation = True
        
        if run_animation:
            man1.isAtk_with_mvmt = True
            man1.x += (man1.vel) * 25
            man1.right = False
            man1.left = False
            # when done animating, set the boolean to false
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand why I need to set that boolean... I tried that code and just to test it out, I set run_animation to False outside the main while loop. Also, I set the boolean to False after the animation is done, but the result seems to be the same as before...

Comment: Unfortunate. I thought that'd work as the problem was that the animation was only progressing while the button was pressed. So I thought if there is a boolean that is true when the button is pressed, and the animation runs while that boolean is true it wont stop unless u say so (setting the boolean false)